# Sending datetime form Android to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, datetime

I want to send to MySQL a datetime and a user id. Here is my Android code:

```
try {
                String user = params[1];
                String date = params[2];
                URL url = new URL("http://www.aa.aa/add_signal.php");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8")+"="+date;
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line + "\n";
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Log.d("HERE", "SENDING RESULT");
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'conf/zmienne.php';
    require_once 'inc/baza.php';

    $user=$_GET["user"];
    $date=$_GET["date"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `signals_dates` (`date`, `user`) VALUES ('$date', '$user')";
    $baza->query($query);
    echo 'DONE';
?>
```

And I'm having a new record in a database but it's only zeroes. The `post_data` string for some example data is: `user=1&date=2017-12-15 15:15:15`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong that the data is not saving in the database. I run this `add_signal.php` script in a web browser and it runs well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the PHP code. There may be some issues with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to:

```
try {
                String user = params[1];
                String date = params[2];
                String str_url = add_signal_url+"?user="+user+"&date="+date;
                URL url = new URL(str_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line + "\n";
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Log.d("HERE", "SENDING RESULT");
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And it works. But I have not idea why previous version wasn't.